# Understanding result of parBuffer-based strategy run

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, ghc

I want to understand Haskell Evaluation Strategies, and found the `parBuffer` concept very interesting. So I created a dumb slow function that calculates factorials, and tried to create a parallel version of it.

Consider the code below

```
module Main where

import System.Environment
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

fac :: Int -> Int
fac n
    | n <= 1 = 1
    | otherwise = n * fac (n-1)

-- sequential version
facsum :: Int -> Int
facsum n = sum $ map fac [1..n]

facsum_par :: Int -> Int
facsum_par n = sum lst  where
    lst = (map fac [1..n]) `using` parBuffer 50 rseq

main :: IO ()
main = do args <- getArgs 
          let (n:_) = args 
          print (facsum_par $ read n)
```

I would have expected, that the parBuffer would create bunches of 50 sparks, but the statistics for *n = 9000, and -N2 I get the output

> SPARKS: 9000 (8277 converted, 688 overflowed, 0 dud, 1 GC'd, 34 fizzled)

Why are there overflowed sparks? As far as I understand this only happens if the amount of sparks would be larger than the size of the spark pool, but should this be limited to 50?

Why are there 34 fizzled sparks, is it only for the small, fast-calculating inputs?